# How to to create with excel VBA code or similiar

Tags: excel, vba

I need to some help.

I found a page from a book and I wonder how to create this solution from the beginning to the end?

[image]

Comment: That's when I miss the "Need to demonstrate minimal knowledge" closing reason.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or do you want us to write the whole code for you?

Comment: I do not know where to start. It is totally blackout!

Comment: Maybe start at step 1 and work your way to step 6?  usually jumping in at the middle raises all kinds of problems.

Comment: Start by typing out the sample data into a worksheet. If nothing else, you will have sample data that can be added to your question. See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data?](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le)

Answer (score 1):

Here's your help:

1. Read the first several chapters of your book on how Excel works.
2. Start the Excel Macro Recorder
3. Execute the items in Step 6 of your book
4. Stop the Excel Macro Recorder
5. Look at the code Excel generated for you

Comment: I don't know where to find/locate "Cash Flow" in the excel sheet?

Comment: <cough><cough>T·R·O·L·L<cough>